attribute match multiple substrings
I'm looking to take an nifi attribute and match it to multiple substrings. In order to do this, the substrings need to be saved to an external file as they are numerous and need to be updated easily. The substring matches need to be returned and added as new attributes.
Example flowfile:
{"Name":"A,B"}
Example dictionary:
A,
B
Example attributes:
Match1: A
Match2: B
Firstly I tried ScanContent which takes a dictionary and returns a match (matching.term) but this does not support multiple matches.
Secondly I tried ScanAttribute which also takes an external dictionary. This does support multiple matches but does not return what the matches substring is.

I used ExecuteGroovyScript to write a script to do this

Maybe give a exemple ?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
